# How to search for multiple values in a text file via text boxes and radio buttons?

Tags: php

I'm required to search a text file that has values delimited by commas (","). I have been able to search the file successfully and display results when searching a value through a text box, but scaling up the search with radio buttons has not been successful.

I have tried following the same syntax and added an '||' for the radio button value, show in the code below:

```
$titleSearch = explode(",", $_REQUEST["title"]);
             $positionSearch = explode(",", $_REQUEST["position"]);
             $lines = file("$dir/jobs.txt");
             foreach($lines as $line){
                if(stripos($line, $titleSearch[0]) !== false || stripos($line, $positionSearch[0]) !== false){
                 echo "<tr>";

                 echo "<td>";
                 $data = explode(',', trim($line));
                 echo $data[0];
                 echo "</td>";

                 echo "<td>";
                 echo $data[1];
                 echo "</td>";

//code goes on for a bit...
```

Simply searching "Sys" in the search form will provide this desired result:

```
ID  Title   Description Closing Date    Position    Contract    Application type    Location
P0001   Sys Admin   This is a test description for the assignment.  09/04/19    Full Time   Fixed Term  Post and Mail   VIC
P0002   Sys Admin   This is a test description for the assignment.  09/04/19    Part Time   Fixed Term  Post    QLD
```

However just clicking one of the radio buttons, Full Time or Part Time, will display all results in the text file. I do have an else further down in my code that display all results if no option is selected.

Form code:

```
<p>
 Position:
 <input type="radio" name="position" value="Full Time">Full Time <input 
  type="radio" name="position" value="Part Time">Part Time<br>
</p>
```

I will also be required to search via check boxes and a drop down list further down the line.

Thanks.

Comment: dont use a flat text file, use a database, it will save you a lot of time\pain

Comment: I know it would, unfortunately not allowed to for this assignment.

Comment: if title is blank when you do a position search you will get all results; you need to exclude the title search code if just searching for a position

Comment: I understand that but its not what i'm looking for, even just having the position search yields all results. I would like for the position search to work along with the title search.